# Unique Rows defined by Multiple Columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a table definition where a duplicate is considered only if 3 columns are the same.

```
Accountid, Reportid,  Date (Y-m-d)
1          2          2014-01-01
1          2          2014-01-02
2          2          2014-01-01
1          2          2014-01-01   //Dupe And not let it insert like a primary key
```

Comment: Did you hear about composite keys?

Comment: `ALTER IGNORE TABLE MyTable
ADD UNIQUE KEY my_unique_key_name (accountid, reportid,date)`

Comment: After a quick Search, yes composite key is the answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution Used**

`ALTER IGNORE TABLE MyTable ADD UNIQUE KEY my_unique_key_name (accountid, reportid,date)`

–  Mihai Jan 29 at 19:19